# How to make array from class variables

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to create an array from existing values of class vars in typescript

Eg:

```
export class example{
  static readonly a = 'aval';
  static readonly b = 'bval';
static readonly c = 'cval';
}
```

TO

```
exampleArray = ['aval', 'bval', 'cval'];
```

Note: I want to make it like access all vars values of class in one go and put it in array not like [example.a]

Comment: I hope you are not using a class with *only* static class variables in your actual code. If that'd be the case then you should use a plain object instead.

Answer (score 2):

`Object.values(example)` should work

Comment: I don't think it will work, Because the question is how to make an array from class not object

Comment: @Wajid ... A class in JavaScript is an object too. Thus a class with just static properties has to be treated like an object; in this case one actually should use a plain object at first place.

Comment: class in JS actually a function and function is an object), so static properties of class becomes properties of function/object ⚆ _ ⚆. Please try it, you will see that it works

Comment: @Wajid `console.log(class A{} instanceof Object)` gives `true` though...

Answer (score 1):

```
Object.values(SomethingClass);
```

Will give you an array of the values. But just FYI - I believe it only works for static class members.

To get class members that aren't static, you'd need to instantiate it first.

```
Object.values(new SomethingClass());
```

That would give you only the non-static members.

Comment: I don't think it will work, Because the question is how to make an array from class not object

Comment: @Wajid - it works, I tested it before answering :-)

Comment: @Wajid what makes you think a class is not also an object?